# ListView not builing properly in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working with simple List view using this code,

```
public class RadioDemoActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
MyListAdapter mla;
ListView lv;
int position = -1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
    list.add("three");
    list.add("four");
    list.add("five");
    list.add("six");
    list.add("seven");
    list.add("eight");
    list.add("nine");
    list.add("ten");
    list.add("eleven");
    list.add("twelve");
    list.add("thirteen");
    list.add("fourteen");
    list.add("fifteen");
    list.add("sixteen");
    list.add("seventeen");
    list.add("eightteen");
    list.add("nineteen");
    list.add("twenty");

    mla = new MyListAdapter(this);
    lv.setAdapter(mla);

}


public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_list, null);

            TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            tv.setText(list.get(position));
            Log.v("log_tag","position In"+list.get(position));

        }
        return convertView;
    }
  }
}
```

but result is like in Image
after eleven its showing me one,one, two.
please help me
[image]

Comment: `put the listview inside a scroll view` is one of the stupid thing in android.

Comment: You cant set a ScrollView insode a Listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my getView() like this and problem solved.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_list, null);

        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        tv.setText(list.get(position));
        tv.setTag(list.get(position));

        if (RadioDemoActivity.this.position==position)
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenround);

        return convertView;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ListHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_list, null);
            holder=new ListHolder();
            holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
            holder.iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Log.v("log_tag","position In"+list.get(position));
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
         else
        {
        holder=(ListHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv.setText(list.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
 static class ListHolder
{
    TextView tv;

    ImageView iv;
}
```

Always write else condition in holder.

Comment: Sorry mybad I have not seen `holder.tv.setText(list.get(position));`

Comment: Check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079460/android-how-to-retrieve-the-holder-elements-in-a-listview-adapter

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem Than why you wrote that - "I dont think this will work" ??

Comment: I think I made my `Sorry` in above comment..:)

Answer (score 1):

change your `getView()` to:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_list, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tv.setText(list.get(position));
    Log.v("log_tag","position In"+list.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't add the comment in "right" place, but Niteesh Mehra's suggestion above to put LV in scrollview is wrong. LV is a view that shows items in a vertically scrolling list, so there's no point of doing so again.

As for your problem - your getView() implementation is wrong. You should **reuse** view given if convertView is not null, but reuse means you got **view** (layout) already baked, but you still have to fill it with content right for this row. So you should do something like:

```
if( convertView == null ) {
 convertView = <inflate view from XML>;
}
```

Then you your data in view's elements **unconditionally**.

Answer (score 0):

change `getView` method like this

```
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_list, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv.setText(list.get(position));
        Log.v("log_tag","position In"+list.get(position));
```